# Operators after findallAsync().asFlowable() are running on the UI thread

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

I'm facing with a problem, rxjava operators are running in the UI thread.
I'm using findAllAsync() to get object asynchronously and using asFlowable() to treat them with rxjava operator.

```
realm.where(Specie.class)
            .equalTo("fauna", true)
            .findAllAsync().asFlowable()
            .filter(new Predicate<RealmResults<Specie>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(RealmResults<Specie> species) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("THREAD : " + Thread.currentThread().getId()); // Print 1
                    return species.isLoaded();
                }
            })
```

But in the realm rxjava example they are using observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) , it means the previous operators are running asynchronously otherwise it would be useless.
Link : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/rxJavaExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/rxjava/animation/AnimationActivity.java

```
disposable = realm.where(Person.class).findAllAsync().asFlowable()
            .flatMap(persons -> Flowable.fromIterable(persons))
            .zipWith(Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (person, tick) -> person)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(person -> {
                TextView personView = new TextView(AnimationActivity.this);
                personView.setText(person.getName());
                container.addView(personView);
            });
```

How can I run operators after asFlowable() asynchronously ?

> edit : How can I access RealmResults obtained on the UI thread on a
>   background thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution on `Schedulers.computation()`, so they add `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to go back to the main thread.

The Realm Async Query API handles the asynchronous evaluation of the query on its own, and the results of that query are passed back by Realm to the UI thread, that is when `isLoaded()` is true.

To get off the main thread, you can use `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` for example.

Comment: This exception will be thrown : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created." if I use observeOn(Schedulers.io())

Comment: Well **your** question was `How can I run operators after asFlowable() asynchronously ?`, not "how can I access RealmResults obtained on the UI thread on a background thread" :P

Comment: My bad, how can I access to it then ?

Comment: You need to open (then close later) the Realm instance on that thread, and execute the query on that thread to get a result set bound to that thread.

Comment: BTW I answered a very similar question  here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47081800/2413303