# Asynchronous read / write to Realm using RXJava 2

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java, rx-android

My first implementation of an asynchronous operation using `RXJava 2`

**Goal:**

Get `json` data from the server with library `Retrofit2`. If successful, then write the data to `Realm` and immediately after the record get the data back and send to the adapter of `RecyclerView`.

So, I realized all this in this way:

```
private void fetchChatsFromNetwork(int count, AccessDataModel accessDataModel) {

    String accessToken = accessDataModel.getAccessToken();

    MyApplication.getRestApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<ChatsModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(ChatsModel chatsModel) {
                    if (chatsRepository.hasData()) {

                        chatsRepository.updateChatsData(chatsModel)
                                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ChatsModel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(ChatsModel localChatsModel) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onSuccess updated!");
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(localChatsModel);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onError when update!");
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(e.getMessage());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        dispose();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onComplete!");
                                    }
                                });

                    } else {
                        chatsRepository.insertChatsData(chatsModel)
                                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ChatsModel>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(ChatsModel localChatsModel) {
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(localChatsModel);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onSuccess inserted!");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                        iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(e.getMessage());
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onError when inserting!");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        dispose();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DO, onComplete!");
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError" + t.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete");
                }
            });
}
```

I write the data in `Realm` in the `onNext()` method of the subscriber `MyApplication.getRestApi().GetChats()`

Here is the entry code:

```
public Observable<ChatsModel> updateChatsData(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {

    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<ChatsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<ChatsModel> e) throws Exception {
            if (chatsModel != null) {
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(
                        realm -> realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chatsModel),
                        () -> {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data success updated!");
                            ChatsModel localChatsModel = getAllChatsData();
                            e.onNext(localChatsModel);
                            e.onComplete();
                        },
                        error -> {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Update data failed!");
                            e.onError(error);
                        });
            }

        }
    });

}
```

The `updateChatsData()` writes asynchronously and declared in another class.

As you can see, the `fetchChatsFromNetwork()` method is written cumbersome or so it seems to me

**Question:**

Whether I am doing right or not, if not, how would that be correct?

Comment: You're overcomplicating it right now, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void fetchChatsFromNetwork(int count, AccessDataModel accessDataModel) {    
    String accessToken = accessDataModel.getAccessToken();
    Single<ChatsModel> chats = MyApplication.getRestApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version);
    chats.doOnNext((chats) -> {
        chatsRepository.insertOrUpdate(chats);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe();
}
```

And

```
public void updateChatsData(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
            r.insertOrUpdate(chatsModel);
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
public Flowable<List<ChatsModel>> getAllChatsData(Realm realm) {
    RealmQuery<ChatsModel> query = realm.where(ChatsModel.class);
    if(realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
        return query.findAllAsync().asFlowable().filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
    } else {
        return Flowable.just(query.findAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: But what about their subscribers. How should they work?

Comment: Only the Flowable needs a subscriber, and in this case (using the RealmResults) you'd update whatever you need to update with it, strictly kept on the UI thread

Comment: not quite understood, it is possible more in detail?

Comment: All the code you wrote above should be replaced with what I wrote.